# How to fix element with jQuery or css at the bottom of the parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In my example I need to fix button `.lot-item .bid-now` to the bottom of `.lot-item` as in jsFiddle example bellow. I know most popular way is to make `position: relative` then of the child element `position: absolute` then `bottom 0`. But in this case all my items will loose `weight` property and will be ugly. Because my buttons most wide elements in the parent element. Also I am not able to make fixed wide `weight` for `.lot-item`. If there are any different solution for my case? jQuery solution is will be good one too

https://jsfiddle.net/z7Lgme5s/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I passed columns to FlexBox, and the results change, I send you the same code in fiddle

The parents .lots are passed to display: flex and flex-wrap: wrap to fall in another line

```
[https://jsfiddle.net/r0bin/0m13h5fk/1/][1]
```

Comment: Many thanks. That's solved my issue. Flex-wrap: wrap is very useful